# depressed husband

Tags: marriage

My husband is incapable of marital relations due to antidepressants and psychological issues.  This came as a shock after marriage.  I was too ashamed and embarrassed to seek help, and my mother kept urging me to try to work it out.  However, there are some things I cannot change.  We have two children by artificial insemination.  I don't plan on breaking up the family, but I long for normal marital relations.  How can I live a virtuous life under these circumstances?

Comment: speak to Dr Avraham Twerski http://www.abrahamtwerski.com

Comment: Hello, @lilah, and welcome to Mi Yodeya. I'm very sorry to hear about your difficult circumstances. Unfortunately, this site [does not offer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) personal advice or counseling. I'd urge you to [find a rabbi](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi) or counselor you can trust to help give you guidance for your situation. All the best.

Comment: It is an emergency case of consultation with a very competent Dayan.

Comment: practical question needs to be asked to a acredited Dayan only. This website is not allowed to give you an answer.